# Fatal error after instantiating block in Magento

Tags: ajax, magento, block

I am trying to load in a block using ajax in Magento. To accomplish this the controller needs to create a block and pass through an array of data to the block's template. This part is quite simple and I have it working.

However, the template that gets called is also trying to call a block and `setData`:

```
$this->getChild('customerfriends.event.edit')->setData(
    'event', $event);
echo $this->getChild('customerfriends.event.edit')->toHtml();
```

`$this` does not seem to be an object which is causing a fatal error.

Is there something that I need to put in my class?

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Block_Event_Listsection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `$this` *does not seem to be an object which is causing a fatal error.*

If the template is being invoked, then `$this` *has* to be a class instance; ref [`Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L241), and trace back from there. The issue is that your code assumes that there is a child block of `$this` with the **alias** of `customerfriends.event.edit` and immediately performs an object operation (`$returnedObject->setData()`).

The resolution to your issue depends on determining *how* the block with the **alias** of `customerfriends.event.edit` is being assigned as a child to whatever block instance `$this` is. In Magento this could occur via layout XML in one of three ways:

One:

```
<reference name="theParentBlock">
    <block name="customerfriends.event.edit" ... />
</reference>
```

Two:

```
<reference name="theParentBlock">
    <action method="insert"><block>customerfriends.event.edit</block></action>
</reference>
```

Three:

```
<block name="customerfriends.event.edit" ... parent="theParentBlock" />
```

This can also be done directly in PHP, typically in the controller after `loadLayout()` or similar is called.

Also, be aware that parent blocks (`$this` in your case) "know" their children by an alias. When no alias is specified, the block's name in layout is used as the alias. You can recognize an alias in layout XML as the `as` attribute or as the fourth argument to the `insert` action:

```
<reference name="theParentBlock">
    <block name="customerfriends.event.edit" ... as="theAlias" />
</reference>
```

and

```
<reference name="theParentBlock">
    <action method="insert">
        <block>customerfriends.event.edit</block>
        <sibling />
        <after />
        <alias>theAlias</alias>
    </action>
</reference>
```

You can see the parent's list of children by doing the following:

```
Zend_Debug::dump(array_keys($this->getChild()));
```